# Two segues passing the same data from one view controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I need help understanding navigation using segues and can't find a suitable answer here or in the Apple documentation.

I am building a meditation audio player.

I have a main 'ViewController' which shows a table of different meditations.

I have a 'SecondViewController' which plays the meditations' audio files.

I have some free ones and some paid ones.

I am using NSUserDefaults to store a dictionary with information about if the meditation has been purchased or not.

If the  user clicks on a table cell in the main 'ViewController' it should check to see if it has been purchased or not.

If purchased I want the 'SecondViewController' to show and I want to pass it two variables.
If not purchased I want the 'PurchaseViewController' to show and I also need to pass the same two variables.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row

    if pDictionary[purchasedArray[index!]]=="Purchased"||pDictionary[purchasedArray[index!]]=="Included"{
        let medSegueIdentifier = "sendDataSegue"
            if segue.identifier == medSegueIdentifier {
                index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row}
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController
        destination!.medName = names[index!]
        destination!.purchased = true

    } else if pDictionary[purchasedArray[index!]]=="NotPurchased"{
        let medSegueIdentifier = "purchaseSegueIdentifier"
            if segue.identifier == medSegueIdentifier {                  
                index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row}
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? PurchaseViewController
        destination!.medName = names[index!]
        destination!.purchased = false
    }
```

The first branch of the if statement (if purchased) works perfectly but the second (if not purchased) gives an error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

The `destination!.medName` is showing as `nil`, but only in the second branch. This is the part I cannot understand.

Here is [a screenshot of my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8V5K.png).

Comment: You sure you added **purchaseSegue** in the story board, while connecting to PurchaseViewController? if not while creating relationship add **"purchaseSegue"** between relationship of **ViewController** and **PurchaseViewController**

Comment: Yes... The segue to 'SecondViewController' has an Identifier of 'sendDataSegue' and the segue to 'PurchaseViewController' has an identification of 'purchaseSegueIdentifier'

Answer (score 0):

The only way for `destination` being `nil` is i that the cast didn't work. So I think that the `segue.destinationViewController` is not an instance of `PurchaseViewController`

To double check open the storyboard, select your viewcontroller and open the attribute inspector. Check there the name of the class.

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to check for that but...
On the Storyboard for 'PurchaseViewcontroller' there is a relationship shown in the 'PRESENTING SEGUES' section.
show --> ViewController   manual

Comment: thanks for the clarification.
.

My 'SecondViewController' has 'SecondViewController' as the Class,
The 'ViewController' has 'ViewController' as the Class
and the 'PurchaseViewController' has 'PurchaseViewController' as the Class